# How do you append an array inside an object?

Tags: javascript

I have an array inside an object, I like to update the language from en to german . If the user is providing german language for months it should take german language as a month else default to be english month. I am trying to update the months array with ternary operator but its not working. can you please suggest ?

```
const Language = {
  months: [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
  ],
  weekDays: [
    {
      name: 'Sunday',
      short: 'Sun',
    },
    {
      name: 'Monday',
      short: 'Mon',
    },
    {
      name: 'Tuesday',
      short: 'Tue',
    },
    {
      name: 'Wednesday',
      short: 'Wed',
    },
    {
      name: 'Thursday',
      short: 'Thu',
    },
    {
      name: 'Friday',
      short: 'Fri',
    },
    {
      name: 'Saturday',
      short: 'Sat',
    },
  ],
  
};
```

I am trying to update like below

```js
const germanLanguage = german_months :[
   months: [
    'yah-noo-ahr',
    'fay-broo-ahr',
    'mehrtz',
    'ah-pril',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
  ]
]

const Language = {
 germanLanguage ? germanLanguage : months: [
   'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
  ],
  weekDays: [
    {
      name: 'Sunday',
      short: 'Sun',
    },
    {
      name: 'Monday',
      short: 'Mon',
    },
    {
      name: 'Tuesday',
      short: 'Tue',
    },
    {
      name: 'Wednesday',
      short: 'Wed',
    },
    {
      name: 'Thursday',
      short: 'Thu',
    },
    {
      name: 'Friday',
      short: 'Fri',
    },
    {
      name: 'Saturday',
      short: 'Sat',
    },
  ],
  
};
```

Comment: *"I am trying to update the months array with ternary operator"* - Where are you trying to do that?  How is it failing?

Comment: Look at the browser's development console.  You have syntax errors.  It's not clear what you're expecting that syntax to mean.  Did you just forget to wrap object literals in curly braces?

Comment: day's names are not `Sunday...` in german...

Comment: I just added example

Comment: @sheeba: And in that example you're struggling considerably with basic syntax when just trying to define objects and arrays.  You're going to need to be able to do that before you can do whatever you're trying to do with a ternary conditional operator.  For example, in your code when you define `const germanLanguage`, what are you expecting that variable to have?  An array?  An object with a property that is an array?  Something else?  Some introductory tutorials on objects and arrays in JavaScript would be a great first step for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the `weekDays` array inside your `Language` object this code can help you :

```
const weekDaysInGerman = [{}, {}, ...];
const GermanLanguage = {...Language, weekDays: weekDaysInGerman};
```